# Is possible to provide new fields for existing entities from modules in XAF applications?

Tags: .net, devexpress, xaf

Imagine you produced your first XAF application, now you are extending your product with an module for some customers only. This module can extend existing entities with new fields.

May be this possible? If not what alternative mindset does exist?

Answer (score 0):

of course i'ts possible, you can add new fields, reports, dashboard, validation rules.. ect all at runtime.